# Manga involving a mountain zombie boy who saves two girls from kidnappers

Tags: story-identification, manga, zombie, cultivation

I can't remember a manga I read a few years ago.

This started in full color then it turned into black and white.

The story stats with...

These kidnappers demanding the village head to lead them through the forest. His daughter with a broken leg and crutches then steps up and says she will take them. It then proceeds with this girl guiding the kidnappers through the forest (they have a kidnapped girl with them who is a disciple of some sort, she's in a bag they are carrying) and they are attacked by a big bear-thing (I think it was called like an iron claw bear) and the kidnappers get killed. Before the two girls die, a mountain zombie boy (named Gordon Fritz, I think) saves both of them and brings them into his underground home.

He is the protagonist and he has white hair and has one eye that's all messed up (it's just the socket and the skin around it is messed up). The two girls wake up there and the boy doesn't know how to interact with them, due to have been asleep there for a long time in a coffin.

He offers them food (meat from animals he has killed. He only drinks blood from animals so the meat he just lets rot in a room down the hall). And of course they don't trust him at first but they don't really have a choice, plus he is stupid and friendly so...

This is not a zombie apocalypse story; he is the only one who is a zombie. He was made a zombie as a cultivation practice thing.

Then the girl who was the guide goes back to her village and Gordon and the girl go on an adventure to where she is from, because he wants to be a human again.

She teaches him cultivation, which she tests by turning the floor into glass with him. And then she almost gets kidnapped again by a guy who uses young girls as hangers after removing their eyes.

I know a lot about the story so if you have any questions at all let me know!

If anyone knows what this is please let me know! Really wanna read it again! Been searching for over a year!

Comment: Also asked [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/18t23yj/help_cant_remember_title_mc_is_a_zombie_saves_2/) (not answered) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/18wj45h/tomt_mangamanhwa_help_cant_remember_title_mc_is_a/) (not answered).

Comment: Does this scene take place at the very beginning? i.e. does the story open with the kidnappers going up to mountain? Is Gordon the protagonist?

Comment: What audience was this intended for? Was there gore/violence/sexiness?